# How do I use string manipulation to convert xml comments to dgv?

Tags: c#, xml, string

I am working on a small project that to convert an xml comments page build in visual studio. I am 80% there, but I am stuck when it comes to selecting multiple parameters. I am able to return a single parameter name and description, but returning multiple parameters is what I am having a problem. Here is an example(After several hours of frustration and retrying, this code may be more sloppy than normal):

```
<member name="M:EvalServiceLibrary.EvalService.SubmitEval(EvalServiceLibrary.Eval)">
        <summary>
        Submit a new evaluation
        </summary>
        <param name="eval">Instance of the eval object without an ID</param>
        <param name="fake">Fake paramter for testing</param>        
    </member>      

public List<string> AssignParamData(List<string> allMemberData, string startString, string endString)
    {
        List<string> matched = new List<string>();
        int indexStart = 0, indexEnd = 0, indexFinal = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < allMemberData.Count(); i++)
        {
            bool exit = false;

            if (allMemberData[i].ToString().Contains("<param name=") == true)
            {
                indexStart = allMemberData[i].IndexOf(startString);
                string tempName = allMemberData[i];
                tempName = tempName.Substring(indexStart, (tempName.Length - indexStart));
                indexEnd = tempName.IndexOf(endString);                    
                tempName = tempName.Substring(indexFinal,indexEnd).Substring(13);


                matched.Add(tempName);
            }
            else
            {
                matched.Add("");
            }
        }
        return matched;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What concrete problem are you facing?

Comment: I am unable to separate the parameters. I can only get it to show both parameters together, including the first </param> and <param name="fake">, for example

Comment: You could write an XSLT script to do this too.